# Exporting cloud masked MODIS image collection from google earth engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am working on cloud masking, on a collection of Modis images in google earth engine.The code below works for the cloud masking part however when i try exporting the collection it returns an error as below 
Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type. Expected: Image. Actual: ImageCollection.
[image: error returned]
I don't know where the problem is that is causing the error

```
var maskEmptyPixels = function(image) {
  var withObs = image.select('EVI').gt(0);
  return image.updateMask(withObs); 
  };
var maskClouds = function(image) {
  var QA = image.select('SummaryQA');
  var bitMask = 1 << 10;
  return image.updateMask(QA.bitwiseAnd(bitMask).eq(0));
}; 
var table_bounds = function(image){
 return image.clip(table); 
};
var collection =ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1' )
               .filterDate('2019-03-01', '2019-07-30')
                .filterBounds(table).select('EVI','SummaryQA')
                .map(maskEmptyPixels);
var evicollection = collection.map(table_bounds);
var totalObsCount = evicollection
        .select('EVI')
        .count();
var collectionCloudMasked = evicollection.map(maskClouds);
var clearObsCount = collectionCloudMasked
        .select('EVI')
        .count()
        .unmask(0);
Map.setCenter(35.94,-0.37,8);
Map.addLayer(
    collectionCloudMasked.median(),
    {bands: ['EVI'],
     gain: 0.07,
     gamma: 1.4
    },
    'median of masked collection'
  );
  print(collectionCloudMasked);
var list = collectionCloudMasked.toList(11);
for(var i=1;i<11;i++){
  var nam=ee.String('EVI_img')
             .cat(ee.String(ee.Number(i)))
             .getInfo();
}
Export.image.toDrive({   
       image: collectionCloudMasked,
       description: nam,
       scale:250,
       maxPixels:1e13
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only export a single image using the `Export.toDrive()`. Make sure the for loop you provide return a name and a corresponding image, and then export it within the loop. Note also that GEE list start index is zero.

```
var list = collectionCloudMasked.toList(11);
for(var i=0;i<11;i++){
  // make a client-side name for export
  var nam = ee.String('EVI_img')
             .cat(ee.String(ee.Number(i)))
             .getInfo();

  // get the image from the collection.toList()
  var imgExport = ee.Image(list.get(i))

  Export.image.toDrive({   
         image: imgExport,
         description: nam,
         scale:250,
         maxPixels:1e13
  });
}
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7310043343de6db57e865735d838b406)

Comment: It is because this line `var imgExport = ee.Image(list.get[i])` is wrong. It should be `var imgExport = ee.Image(list.get(i))`.

Comment: Thanks ,,,it worked.

Comment: @Patricia If it worked, you should mark the answer as accepted.